# Goldstone Bosons and Criticality

Tags: phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, critical-phenomena, goldstone-mode

In the presence of spontaneous symmetry breaking of a continuous symmetry, there are massless goldstone bosons. However, they are not treated in the discussions of critical phenomena. Naively I would assume that as the correlation length is infinite, this theories would be on the critical surface and flow to a CFT in the IR limit. One difference I can see is that criticality occurs when there is a phase transition which is not the case for SSB. However I don't see why SSB can't be treated in a similar way to critical phenomena in the IR limit.

Comment: In spontaneous symmetry breaking, there is an energy scale associated with the expectation value of the order parameter, and there are observables related to this energy scale. Under successive RG transformations, this energy scale goes to infinity, and you're eventually left with the theory of massless non-interacting Goldstone bosons, which is the CFT you are looking for.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt are you saying that if I take an interacting theory with continuous spontaneous symmetry breaking, its IR behaviour is trivial ? Then wouldn't one should be able to solve O(N) models without large N limit (to give an example) ?

Comment: @Bronsteinx Yes, but it is only the strict IR/scaling limit that is trivial. The ordered phase of the O(N) models asymptotically flows to the theory of (N-1) free massless bosons, which is solvable. But taking this limit right away removes a lot of interesting and relevant physics at intermediate energy scales.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt thanks for the response. I would appreciate any reference. Although it seems like your argument seems to be it, i feel a bit uneasy about integrating out angular variables.

Comment: @Bronsteinx See for example Section 8.1 in Kardar's *Statistical Physics of Fields*, which performs RG on the O(N) non-linear sigma model (NLSM) and shows that the action is that of (N-1) massless fields plus irrelevant corrections for small T for D>2. The relation between the NLSM and the ordered phase of phi^4 theory is discussed in Zinn-Justin's critical phenomena book or Peskin & Schoeder for example.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt thanks a lot again. I have looked at relevant sections. It seems to me that this is triviality of O(N) is shown only for low T/weak coupling. Zinn-Justin explicitly states this, for example the range of "pion fields" are taken to be the real line in almost every discussion i have seen, however they should be constrained to be in a ball and integration over real line only holds for weak coupling. Are you also saying that the "triviality" holds always as long as you are in the broken phase ?

Comment: @Bronsteinx I’m not assuming weak coupling, I’m assuming that one has taken the RG flow to its endpoint, and what one can show is that the endpoint is identical to zero T/zero coupling. Another way to think about it: the “ball” which the pions live on (e.g. the (N-1)-sphere for the O(N) models) has energy scales associated with it (local curvature or global volume) which go to zero or infinity under RG, leaving you with just free scalars (non compact flat space). It’s really just that the endpoints under RG are usually trivial, with interacting CFTs being the special fine-tuned exceptions.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt How you are showing that RG flows end up at same point. My understanding is that at weak coupling we can show that things flow zero temperature and you assume that there is only one critical temperature so you there will be two RG end points disregarding the critical one. But this is an assumption right ? Not something you can really show.

Comment: @Bronsteinx I see, I didn’t understand the level of mathematical rigor you were asking for. I’m not familiar with the mathematical physics literature but I have always been satisfied with the preponderance of evidence for only one finite-T critical point in the O(N) models. Here is a nice post on the proof for only one critical point for Ising models which mentions that these proofs are indeed very hard: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/423979/244199. Perhaps you can ask abkut O(N) models as a separate question, Yvan Velenik is certainly the person to ask re: these more rigorous results.